# djang-bootstrap avoid label tag being added when calling `field|bootstrap`

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter, django-crispy-forms, django-bootstrap4

How to avoid label tag being added when calling `field|bootstrap`. I have the below code

**filter.py**

```
import django_filters
from .models import Issue

class IssuesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    summary = django_filters.CharFilter(label="Summary", lookup_expr="icontains")
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
```

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
    issues = IssuesFilter(request.GET, queryset=Issue.objects.all())
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'message': 'LogedIn',
        'filter': issues
    }
    return render(request, 'testApp/index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "firstPage/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block body %}
<form method="GET">
  <table>
  {% for field in filter.form %}
      <tr class="table table-borderless">
          <td>{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
          <td>{{ field|bootstrap }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

When I add `field|bootstrap` I could see the label tag of the field is displayed. Is it possible to remove additional label tag from being added?

[image: Screenshot after adding field|bootstrap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this comes very late but if anyone is dealing with the same problem you can find the answer in the documentation

https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap4.templatetags.bootstrap4.bootstrap_field

```
{% bootstrap_field field show_label=False %}
```